# Record username and score then append to list using functions

Tags: python

I am trying to write code using functions. I am supposed to ask for a name and grade until the user sends an empty string ''. Then put those inputs into a list.

Example:

```
[["Name","Grade"],["Name2","Grade2"],["Name3","Grade3"]]


def getRec():
    while True:
        name=[]
        if name != '':
            name=input('Enter name: ')
            score=input('What is score: ')
            if name !='':
                tab=[]
                def addList():
                    tab.append(name)
                    tab.append(score)
                addList()
                print(tab)
        if not name:
            break
getRec()
```

So far I have been trying all day today and yesterday but I can't seem to understand what I am missing. It looks like my name and scores are being overwritten by the new inputs.

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? Use a debugger (or a pen and paper) and step through what you've written line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed overwriting your list when you redefine the list back to empty after each loop. Here's a smarter method.

```
my_list = []
def getRec():
    while True:
        name = input('What name: ')
        score = input('What score: ')
        if name == '':
            print(my_list)
            break
        tab = []
        tab.append(name)
        tab.append(score)
        my_list.append(tab)
getRec()
```

Answer (score 0):

You completely redefine `tab=[]` for each name, wiping out what was input before. Put that line before the `while True` loop  and see if that helps.